# Token receipt handler in smart contracts with Solidity

Tags: contract-development, tokens

Is it possible to define a handler which is executed every time when tokens are transferred to a contract? I.e. something like an unnamed function for Ether but for user tokens:

```
function() public payable {
    // handle ETH
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For EIP-20 tokens there is no such mechanism.

[For ERC-223 tokens please refer to the token standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223) and look for `tokenFallback` function.

Comment: You meant ERC-20 tokens?

Comment: No, the ERC-20 proposal is finalized, so it is no longer "Candidate" https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/ and can be referred as Ethereum Improvement Proposal.

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks. One more question - what for is Receiver_Interface implementation https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC223-token-standard/blob/Recommended/Receiver_Interface.sol ? As far as I understand it is simply interface which should be inherited by contract that is going to receive tokens and implemented in such way that contract owner prefers. Then why there are not empty functions like in   ERC223_Interface https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC223-token-standard/blob/Recommended/ERC223_Interface.sol but TKN struct and implemented tokenFallback etc?

Comment: I think this is another question on this site or even the question to the author of the project.

Answer (score 0):

if you use an ERC-20 tokens, you can't use fallback function  for tokens.

You can see other standards for tokens:

ERC-23

[ERC-223](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223)

[ERC-777](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/777)